# echo smbpasswd by --stdin doesn't work

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to make creating a samba password automated but this command doesn't work:

```
echo "passwd"|smbpasswd -a -s $user
```

It shows this error:

> Mismatch - password unchanged.
>   Unable to get new password.

Could you please suggest any option to make my script automated?

Answer (score 21):

You need to *repeat* the password, "for confirmation" so to speak, so e.g.

```
printf "passwd\npasswd\n" | smbpasswd -a -s $user
```

should work.

Comment: agree with your point but could you please tell in short whatz a function of printf at here

Comment: `printf` is a shell command specified in IEEE Std 1003.2-1992 (``POSIX.2'') that's more powerful than `echo` because it easily lets you specify formatting options -- `man 1 printf` (not to be confused with `man 3 printf` which documents the similar function in the C standard library) will give you all the details.

Answer (score 1):

The printf solution above works perfect, but also echo -e works fine

```
echo -e "yourpass\nyourpass\n" |smbpasswd -a -s youruser
```